# Huge number of visits

Tags: discussion, moderation, up-votes

In the first 24 hours after posting, [Identity column re-seed: when it is necessary?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223392/identity-column-re-seed-when-it-is-necessary)  garnered about 700 Visits.  Was it real?  Was it some form of hacking?

(I'm not complaining; my Answer got a lot of upvotes at the same time.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. It might have been featured on the Hot Network Questions list.
2. Perhaps someone tweeted it.
3. Without access to question referrer statistics, it's tough to know *for sure* where those views came from.  Safe to say its *not* hacking, with all the far higher value targets out there.

Comment: Yeah it hit the HNQ, as did [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/223496) at about the same time. It also has 700+ views.

Comment: Curiously, the HNQ event doesn't seem to have registered on [the timeline for that post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/223392/timeline)

Comment: @PeterVandivier It hit HNQ before events started being added see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324643 for a rough indication of when this started. I don't have a precise date.